# Error while deploy my django website on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I created a personal portfolio website using django and it also includes a blog. You can see the exact directory listing and source code in my github repository by clicking [here](https://github.com/ikushum/First-django-website)

I have the procfile and the requirements.txt files as said in the heroku website and did the following in command prompt as directed by heroku :

```
$ heroku login 
$ heroku git:clone -a appname
$ cd appname
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

Now I see the following error while deploying and the push fails :

```
Warning: Your application is missing a Procfile. This file tells Heroku how to run your application.
```

Yes there is a procfile in the directory though.
Please help me deploy this website in heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is called Procfile.txt. It should be called just Procfile.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you made a `.txt` file instead of a non-extension one or that you named it `procfile` and not `Procfile`. Heroku is sensitive about capitalisation.